# contenteditable and non button elements

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I can easily do execcommand on a contenteditable selection if using a button. However using any other element fails.

http://jsbin.com/atike/edit

Why is this and how can I make it work using a div element.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice complete test case.

Comment: The WMD editor stackoverflow uses manages to maintain the selection in the textbox when clicking the toolbar buttons. The buttons are implemented as `<li>` elements not dissimilar to your example. It's not using `contenteditable` of course, but maintains the selection nonetheless. May be of interest, the WMD editor on github: http://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/wmd.js

Comment: I had a look at the WMD editor and there is code in there to remember the selection when clicking a toolbar button, then re-apply that selection afterwards.  Manipulating a selection in a textarea is a bit simpler because it's just a start and end number rather than a range object.  But it looks like a principle that would be useful to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could save the selection by using the `mousedown` event on the element being used instead of a button and restore it again after focussing the editable element in the `click` event.

I've modified the example code: http://jsbin.com/atike/40/edit. Here's the code:

```
function saveSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            var ranges = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
            }
            return ranges;
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function restoreSelection(savedSel) {
    if (savedSel) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            for (var i = 0, len = savedSel.length; i < len; ++i) {
                sel.addRange(savedSel[i]);
            }
        } else if (document.selection && savedSel.select) {
            savedSel.select();
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
  var savedSel;

  $('.bold').mousedown(function () {
    savedSel = saveSelection();
  });

  $('.bold').click(function () {
    $('#hello').focus();
    if (savedSel) {
      restoreSelection(savedSel);
    }
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);    
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - have a bounty.  I now have a rich text editor with working buttons.  The reason I couldn't go with unselectable/mousedown overriding was that some controls in the rich text editor, such as inserting a link, actually need to be able to have text focus.

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, of the WYSIWYG editors out there use an `iframe` element in order to not lose the selection. Another approach, although I haven't tried it, would be to store each selection made on that page after the `mouseup` event triggers.

Take a look at this page about [Midas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Midas), Gecko's built-in rich text editor.

Comment: Well it's definitely not all. Many editors, including google docs, do not use iframe. They must do it somehow.

Comment: I checked and realized one of the editors i was thinking of was just using buttons.

Comment: @Mark which one?  If I choose to use buttons, I'd need to figure out how to style them.

Comment: Styling HTML buttons is not difficult: http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/styling-form-buttons/.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you click a text node, the browser wants to select that text. Buttons are not a part of the text flow and will therefore not trigger a new selection.

All you have to do is prevent the browser from performing a re-selection. When the `click` event you are currently observing runs the selection has already occurred and it's too late to act. The action starts to take place on `mousedown` for all browsers expect MSIE, which has a special selection events.

This works for me across browsers:

```
jQuery('.bold')
  .attr('unselectable','on') // prevents selection in MSIE
  .bind('mousedown',function (e) {
    document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents selection in all but MSIE
  });
```

There are a few complications with using MSIE's selection events (such as having to block dragging as well), so it's easier just to knock out the selectability of the element you are using as a button with the specialized attribute `unselectable` (needs the value "on").

You can obviously still perform the `execCommand` handling in `click` events and just run the selection prevention code on all elements intended as "buttons":

```
jQuery('.buttonlike')
  .attr('unselectable','on') // prevents selection in MSIE
  .bind('mousedown',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents selection in all but MSIE
  });

jQuery('#edit-bold').click(function(){
  document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) uses a combination of methods.

- Most toolbar elements have the "unselectable" attribute set - this works for Internet Explorer.
- On the same elements, it registers for the "mousedown" event and overrides the default action - this prevents both text solution and focus.  This is for browsers other than IE only.
- Some toolbar elements need to be able to receive text focus and make selections, such as the field for inserting a link or image.  For these, it saves the selection before the editor loses focus, then restores it after the user has finished editing and the changes need to be made.

  For how to implement it, check NicEdit's code.  Search for the function names:

  - getSel
  - getRng
  - selRng
  - saveRng
  - restoreRng

  ...

  This uses the browser's getSelection() or document.selection to get the selection, getRangeAt() to convert it to a range, and addRange() or select() to restore that range to as a selection.