# Losing selection when clicking checkbox label

Tags: javascript, checkbox, selection, contenteditable

I am trying to get a checkbox with a label to function so that when you have text selected in a contenteditable `div`, clicking on the `label` will not lose the selection from the `div`. The label still needs to apply the standard checkbox tick/untick upon clicking it, but keep the focus & selection intack on the `div`.

Doing a simple `focus()` on the `div` won't help as the selection will be gone (and caret is at the beginning). I could of course look into a way for storing the `selection` object and trying to assign it back after the `label` click, but isn't there any simpler way of keeping the `selection`?

(the reason I need to do this with `label` & `checkbox` is because I will be using jQuery UI buttons and I will need the the toggle functionality of them)

<strike>On a similar note, if you click the checkbox, you usually still keep the selection in the `div`, but at least on FF4, if you press the checkbox very frequently (<1s), it will lose the selection. Any idea what's going on there?</strike>   **answered below**

**example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gULM9/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's a Firefox bug marked 490367.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490367)

According to the bug description, double-click functionality on `input` fields will act unusually when there is a `contenteditable div` on the page.

I noticed the strange behavior while trying to replicate it manually so I guessed it was a bug. I don't know of any workarounds.

Comment: That would only explain the second part of the problem though, still an open question regarding the label click's.

Comment: The highlight/selection remains if the checkbox itself is clicked, but is lost if the label (or another DIV) is clicked.  Is that the behavior you're seeing too?

Comment: @Niklas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479784/contenteditable-and-non-button-elements

Comment: @Tim Yes, clicking the checkbox works fine, but clicking the label doesn't. Using selections as mentioned in my question of course is an option, but I'd really prefer to explore any other available options before going with that route.

Comment: As a workaround, you use an <a href="#"></a> and the selection remains.